# Output subdivisions of international standard paper sizes

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, recursion

**ISO Paper Sizes Defined:**

The A series paper sizes are defined by the following requirements:

```
The length divided by the width is the square root of 2.
The A0 size has an area of 1 unit.
Each subsequent size A(n) is defined as A(n-1) cut in half parallel to its shorter sides.
```

[image]

**Task:**

given an input `f[n]` output A0 divided into `n` subdivisions.

**Test cases:**

`f[1]` to `f[12]`:

[image]

*Here, A0 is given by* `f[1]`*, but this indexing isn't essential.*

**Winning criteria:**

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Shouldn't `f[2]` be an `A0` with a horizontal line dividing it? i.e., isn't the `f[2]` in the test case actually `f[3]`?

Comment: @JungHwanMin adjusted now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## BBC BASIC 49 ASCII characters

**Tokenised filesize 44 bytes**

```
I.n:F.i=0TOn:RECTANGLE0,0,1189>>i/2+.5,841>>i/2N.
```

Much shorter than before! I always forget about the bitshift operators in BBC BASIC for windows as they weren't available on my old computer back in the day.

## BBC BASIC 63 ASCII characters

**Tokenised filesize 58 bytes**

Dowload interpreter at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/download.html

```
A%=841C%=1189d=4I.n:F.i=0TOn:RECTANGLE0,0,C%,A%:d!^B%/=2d=-d:N.
```

Uses zero indexing, which I prefer. Thus 0 outputs the paper for A0, 1 outputs A0 divided into a pair of A1s, etc.

It is necessary to alternate between halving the X and Y coordinates, but doing that in an array would have cost too many bytes. Instead I use the fact that BBC basic has a block of static integer variables `A%..Z%` of 4 bytes each stored in contiguous memory. I store the X and Y values in `A%` and `C%` and access using the pointer to `%B` modified by the value of d, which alternates between `4` and `-4`.

**Ungolfed**

```
  A%=841
  C%=1189
  d=4
  INPUTn
  FORi=0TOn
    RECTANGLE0,0,C%,A%
    d!^B%/=2
    d=-d
  NEXT
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6) + HTML, <s>96</s> 94 + 34 = <s>130</s> 128 bytes

```js
f=(n,w=297,h=210)=>n--&&f(n,h<w?w/2:w,h<w?h:h/2,(C=c.getContext`2d`).rect(0,0,w,h),C.stroke())

f(8)
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=300 height=300>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>87</s> 85 bytes

Thanks @martin for 1 byte.

```
Graphics@{EdgeForm@Thin,White,Rectangle[#,0{,}]&/@NestList[Sort[#/a]&,{1,a=√2},#]}&
```

Comment: Very nice! `EdgeForm@Thin`: -1 byte

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6)/SVG (HTML5), 170 bytes

```js
a=prompt();document.write('<svg width=297 height=210>');for(w=297,h=210;a--;h>w?h/=2:w/=2)document.write(`<rect fill=none stroke=#000 x=0 y=0 width=${w} height=${h} />`);
```

Uses 1-based indexing.